# why does xmltextreader convert html encoded utf8 characters to utf8 string automatically?

Tags: .net, xml, encoding, xmltextreader

I receive an XML file with encoding "ISO-8859-1" (Latin-1)

Within the file (among other tags) I have `<OtherText>Example &quot;content&quot; And &#9472;</OtherText>`

Now for some reason when I load this into XMLTextReader and do a "XmlReader.Value" to return the  value, it returns: "content" And ─

This then, when confronted with a database only accepting Latin-1 encoding, obviously errors.

I have tried the following:

- Converting into bytes and using
  Encoding.Convert to change from UTF-8
  into Latin-1 (which successfully
  gives me a bunch of "?" instead)
- Using
  StreamReader(file,Encoding.*whatever*)
  to load the file into XmlTextReader

And several variations there-of and different methods on the internet and on StackOverflow istelf.

I understand that .NET strings are UTF-16, but what I don't understand is why, a fully Latin-1 formatted XML file with CORRECT markup for when UTF-8 characters exist which is compatible with older databases AND the web (for HTML markup etc) that it simply overrides that and output's the UTF-8 encoded string ANYWAY.

Is there noway to get around this other than writing my own custom text parser???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe this is a problem with the encoding. What you're seeing is the XML string being un-escaped.

The problem is `&quot;` is a XML escape character, so XMLTextReader will un-escape this for you.

If you change this:

```
<OtherText>Example &quot;content&quot; And &#9472;</OtherText>
```

To this:

```
<OtherText>Example &amp;quot;content&amp;quot; And &amp;#9472;</OtherText>
```

Then

```
   XmlReader.Value = "&quot;content&quot; And &#9472;";
```

You'll need to wrap your value in CDATA so it is ignored by the parser.

Another option is to re-escape the string:

```
    using System.Security;
....
....
    string val = SecurityElement.Escape(xmlReader.Value);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've been staring at the data for almost 12 hours and didn't notice that!

The problem is the data is supplied to me, so there is no way I can impose any changes to it unless I write something to change the ampersand's as indicated. What threw me is they do use &amp; in the text as well.

SecurityElement.Escape appears to work, however, for &#9472; it appears to not pick up that it's UTF-8 and processes it as ASCII, even though MySQL will disagree.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. It still screws up on characters like ā (which was properly encoded, except, as you pointed out, not with &amp;)

So the SecurityElement.Escape() method doesn't work. It appears as if I have to do this myself and somehow not replace valid &amp;'s in the process.

Comment: Thanks to this observation and a combination of the method explained above with:

Dim txt As New StreamReader(filepath)
Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(memoryStream)
streamWriter.Write(txt.ReadToEnd.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&", "&amp;"))
streamWriter.Flush()
memoryStream.Position = 0

Dim xml As New Xml.XmlTextReader(memoryStream)

I was able to successfully write in the data! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!